# Draw a Border but have it not have it inherit object opacity

Tags: css, colors

Please see the following jsBin:

http://jsbin.com/uyonux/1

It is working as desired on the hover state. However the focus state does not work as desired on focus i would like the blue color to not inherit the opacity of .4 i want it the solid #13A3F7 color. Is there any way to append the border without having it use the element opacity?

I tried pseudo elements but they also inherit opacity.

The other solution could be to take 60% plus of #13A3F7 but i don't think that works due to saturation.

I know i could change the image but the point is we are trying to use one black icon and then adjust it with opacity on the various states.

Thanks

```
button {
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAALElEQVR42mNgwA/+QzHZYGAM2E8ADwED6B+I+ynEpPsLzfJBYgBFYTDEMxMA8SA+M9tIcT0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=") ;
  border: none;
  height: 23px;
  width: 26px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  background-position: center center;
}

button:focus {
    border: 1px solid #13A3F7;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #CFCFCF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px #696969;
    opacity: 0.65;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Also I'll need to support IE8 for now :(

Comment: The border is a property of the element itself. It doesn't make sense to tell it not to inherit from the opacity of the element.

Comment: Your right thats probably just a poor way to explain it. What i really want is only the image to be opace and not effect the rest. I realize i can change the image but there is 600 of these so that's the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use outline: instead of border, like this:

```
button:focus, button:active {
  outline: 1px solid #13A3F7 !important;
}
```

**Edit:** You could achieve this by using a link instead of button. Check out this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NZ3lOyFBSxOFwSExyBpA?p=preview

Comment: Outline is also effected by the opacity. Same way as border

Comment: Thanks but the border is still faded and showing at .4 opacity as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [RGBa colors](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).

Like this:

```
border: 10px solid #ff0000;
border-color: rgba( 255,0,0,0.5);
```

Comment: I would change that to "MUST" :)

Comment: Also I'll need to support IE8 for now :(

Comment: Then I think you should make or with images. Best cross browser solution.

Comment: @LinkinTED I'm close to giving up and going that way but there are over 600 of these so its much harder to maintain like that.

Comment: @Tim: Don't give up, check my update Plunker for a working example.